# Using Zenmuse Gimbal Connector for 12V Supply of Laser Scanner

Tags: dji-sdk

we've developped a light weighted survey-grade laser scanner (350 grams) and for practical use it would be perfect to attach it to the gimbal connector as long as it's position assures a good field of sight which is similar to the requirements of a camera. Therefore the idea is to replace the standard gimbal camera (Z3, X3, X5, etc.) with the laser scanner (similar to other 3rd party devices) and use the attachment both for mechanical fixing and for power supply at the same time. Further integration via SDK might be in future, but right now the scanner works independently via GSM (needed anyway for GNSS-RTK) and cloud connection.

My trial setup is as follows (I'm aware that there are several differences between gimbals):

A3 controller
LB2
Camera Adapter (in fact: the gimbal controller itself?) with 3pin + 7pin connectors to LB2 and A3 and power supply direct from battery. Cam connector is 20pin
Gimbal Z3

Mechanical integration is obvious, but I can't get out the 12V power supply. My findings so far:

The controller contains a 12V / 5A regulator and should be more than sufficient for the laser scanner (max. 700 mA against up to 2A for the gimbal)
Pins 12, 14 and 16 which are supposed to carry 12V are in fact open / floating
There is some supply voltage of about 3.2V on the connector (for logic?)
The gimbal initializes even without connection to LB2 or A3 and therefore the question of providing power is something between the gimbal and the adapter
There is a difference in connections of the 20pin connector: Pin 1 and 20 of the gimbal side are grounded, on the adapter side there is a voltage level of 3.2V

It seems that there has to be activated is a switch to provide 12V to the pins and the final question is: HOW?

Is there a magic circuitry needed, e.g. tearing pin 1 or 20 of the adapter to ground?
Or is the 12V output activated via commands on CAN / USB bus between gimbal and adapter?

Any hints are highly appreciated.

Thanks,

DJIMUC

Comment: This site is for questions about writing code. This may be appropriate on the electrical engineering site, but read their site tour first to make sure.

Comment: Well, actually it looks like a _system_ question as long as it is not deceided whether it is solved by HW or SW. Unfortunatelly DJI only refers to this page for support community. Do you have a suggestion for an "engineering site"?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way for integrating with the DJI gimbal connector is through their [Payload SDK](https://developer.dji.com/payload-sdk/) which nominally only supports the Matrice 200 series.  As the interface routes through their SKYPORT adapter which handles the integration with the aircraft, they don't provide anymore details on the gimbal connection itself. Their [hardware introduction](https://developer.dji.com/payload-sdk/documentation/introduction/hardware_introduction.html) page from their Payload SDK documentation may be helpful to you.